# Schedule Import Product not found in admin

Tags: magento2, import, importexport

Magento User guide https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/system/data-scheduled-import-export.html said that

> Scheduled Import/Export is implemented by default, and does not require additional configuration.

But i cannot found this admin section

> System > Data Transfer > Scheduled Imports/Exports

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem with Magento 2.2.4. The doc here also mention a "schedule import button" : https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/system/data-schedule-import.html but I cannot see any of these...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, got it : I have installed the Magento Community Edition (CE) and the doc refers to the Magento Entreprise Edition (EE).